# Kafka cluster security for IOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, iot

I am new to the Kafka and want to deploy Kafka Production cluster for IOT. We will be receiving messages from Raspberry Pi over the internet to our Kafka cluster which we will be hosting on AWS.

Now the concern, since we need to open the KAFKA PORT to the outer internet we are opening a way to system threat as it will compromise with the security by opening port to outer world.

Please let me know what can be done so that we can prevent malicious access using KAFKA port over the internet.

Pardon me if I am not clear with the question, do let me know if rephrasing of queation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a REST Proxy in front of your Kafka brokers (such as the one from Confluent). Then you can secure your Kafka cluster just as you would secure any REST API exposed to the public internet. This architecture is proven in production for several very large IoT use cases.

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking of similar solution wherein I will be sending data using using HTTP POST to kafka server and then push it to KAFKA. But this seems to be a cleaner solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that are most effective for Kafka Security.

1. Implement SSL Encryption for Kafka.
2. Authentication using SASL

You can follow this guide. http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_sasl

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I wanted to know a bit in detail regarding the measures we can take to avoid port abuse. How this will be helpful?

Comment: SASL will be more effective regarding Port abuse as without the authentication the user can't get in. On another note Web Application Firewalls are best options if you want to avoid port abuse but this option depends on your budget as WAF license are very expensive. And Port abuses are very common now a days and there is no any fix solution to avoid that there are only best practices that needs to be followed. There are also various linux tools that you can implement. And another thing that you can use is firewall using security group if you want to provide the access to specify people or dev.